# Is it possible to deploy a tomcat with manager-gui on heroku?

Tags: tomcat, heroku

I tried to deploy tomcat on heroku but it crashes at startup with error code H10.
The goal is to use manager/html for deploying war files.
Ports are set correctly from environment, shutdown port is disabled.
The error log shows:

```
2017-12-11T11:52:15.044454+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-12-11T11:52:18.958330+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `export JAVA_OPTS="-Dserver.port=59582"; ./tomcat/bin/startup.sh`
2017-12-11T11:52:21.651115+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-12-11T11:52:21.629979+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2017-12-11T11:52:21.495507+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2017-12-11T11:52:21.534256+00:00 app[web.1]: Tomcat started.
2017-12-11T12:02:23.057838+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/manager/html" host=my-app.herokuapp.com request_id=1e4f9199-3015-4e4c-8a2f-311c0d97151a fwd="147.86.223.1" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

It works fine locally.
Has anybody ever tried this successfully?

Comment: Ignore me if you've decided on the manager-gui, but the Heroku way of deploying wars would be https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/configuring-war-deployment-with-the-heroku-toolbelt

Comment: The idea is use the manager-gui such that my students can upload their war files for evaluation. Making them use the heroku-upload of war files was too complicated.